# Is Moffat's translation of John 1:1 representative of the original?

Tags: greek, john

The James Moffatt translation renders John 1:1 as:

> THE Logos existed in the very beginning, the Logos was with God, the Logos was divine.

Acknowledging that the original autographs of Scripture are lost to us, is there warrant within the extant manuscripts to render this as "the Logos was divine" rather than "was God"?

Comment: If you're asking about autographs does that mean this is a textual criticism question asking if there is any evidence of an alternate Greek text to the usual NA/UBS text?

Comment: @curiousdannii Representative of the original only insofar as the extant manuscript evidence can take us.  All translations being dependent upon the manuscripts we have to build a case for what was originally written.  If there are alternative greek manuscripts I suppose they may be included but weighed appropriately by their age and authenticity.

Answer (score 5):

According Daniel B Wallace, Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics (GGBB), page 269 -

> The most likely candidate for Θεός [in John 1:1c] is qualitative.
> This is true both grammatically (for the largest proportion of
> pre-verbal anarthrous predicate nominative nominative fall into this
> category) and theologically (both the theology of the Fourth Gospel
> and the NT as a whole) ...

That is, Wallace believes (quite correctly) that in John 1:1c, "the Word was God" is a category statement (such as saying, "my car is a Ford", or, "this animal is a monkey", etc).  Wallace continues in the next paragraph -

> Such an option does not impugn the deity of Christ.  Rather, it
> stresses that, although the person of Christ is not the person of the
> Father, their essence is identical.

Interestingly, in David Bentley Hart's translation of the NT, he attempts to convey the same idea by translating John 1:1c as, "the Logos was god" (small "g").

I believe that the brilliant scholar, Moffatt (with whom I often disagree) attempts to convey the same idea by translating, "the Logos was divine".

Therefore, I agree (in this instance) with Moffatt.  Perhaps, if one insists upon translating nouns with nouns (some do), then  one might "improve" Moffatt's translation by suggesting, "The Word was divinity", but this is awkward.

**What John did NOT write**

John did write this - καὶ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος (literally, the Word was God.)

It is well known that John chose his words very carefully under inspiration.  Here is what John did NOT write:

1. καὶ ὁ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος.  This makes both nouns articular and thus become a convertible proposition as: "The God was the Word" thus making the Father and the Word the same person.
2. Θεὸς ἦν Λόγος = God was Word which is not grammatically correct unless one stretches the translation to "a god was a word".

Comment: So it would not follow then that "Logos was divine" here carries the same connotation as saying that angels are "divine", for example as Biblical Universalists claim?  In other words, "the Logos is God" in a similar way to "the Father is God" is what Moffatt is driving at?

Comment: @MikeBorden - correct on both fronts.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail - the "What John did NOT write" section is really well-said.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at how it's rendered in the Greek (John 1:1 Greek New Testament):

> "᾿Εν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ Λόγος, καὶ ὁ Λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν Θεόν, καὶ
> **Θεὸς** ἦν ὁ Λόγος."

How was the phrase "God was the Word" rendered in Greek? "Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος" (*Theos ēn ho Logos*). Notice that the word *Theos* is without the article *ho*.

What is the difference between *Theos* and *ho Theos*? (Hermeneia – A Critical and Historical Commentary of the Bible, by Ernst Haenchen, p. 109)

> "In order to avoid misunderstanding, it may be asserted here that
> *Theos* and *ho Theos* ('god, divine' and 'the God') were not the same
> thing in this period. Philo has therefore written: '**The *Logos* means
> only *Theos* (‘divine’) and not *ho Theos* (‘God’)** since the logos is not
> God in the strict sense.” Philo was not thinking of giving up Jewish
> monotheism. In a similar fashion, Origen, too, interprets: 'The
> Evangelist does not say that the *logos* is ‘God,’ but only that the
> *logos* is ‘divine.’' In fact, for the author of the hymn, as for the
> Evangelist, only the Father was 'God' (*ho Theos*; cf. 17:3); 'the Son'
> was subordinate to him (cf. 14:28)."

What does *Theos* without the article *ho* mean in this instance? "divine". Hence, the rendering "the *Logos* was divine" is correct.

Comment: Wouldn't it be unnecessary to say "the word was with God and (the) God was the word"?  The definite article isn't needed when the referent is obvious.  To be super specific it might have been "the word was with (the) God and (that) God was the word.".  Not necessary.

Comment: Theos is a common noun and hence requires the article, the same way that Logos is paired with the article in each instance. Also take note that the Word is with God, and if the Word is God in nature and is with another God, that would indicate that there are two Gods, hence the Word is not literally God in nature, but rather divine.

Comment: So then, it should read "the word was with **the** God"?  It being a common noun?  Also in John 1:2, 1:6, 1:12, 1:18, and so many more?  I say in these instances God is being used more as a proper noun, explaining why the definite article is not used.

Comment: @MikeBorden τον in John 1:2 is the accusative form of the article. The other cases are genitive nouns "θεου" rather than "θεος".

Comment: @MikeBorden And yes, "the word was with the God" is the literal translation.

Comment: https://www.abarim-publications.com/Interlinear-New-Testament/John/John-1-parsed.html has it parsed out thus:  in(to) -  to beginning  - he was - the - word - and - the - word - he was - toward - the - God - and - God - he was - the - word.

Comment: @MikeBorden "G2316: θεός (theos); of unc. or.; God, a god: — **divinely** (1), God (1267), god (6), God's (27), God-fearing (1), **godly** (2), godly *(1), gods (8), Lord (1)." 

(New American Standard Exhaustive Concordance of the Bible/Hebrew-Aramaic and Greek Dictionaries)

Comment: 1267 times it's rendered as God and 3 times as divinely or godly?  See Revelation Lad's answer.

Comment: @MikeBorden it's dependant on context. The Word was God is contextually incorrect, and not in harmony with the rest of Scripture.

Comment: (2) The one God was already identified in the verse as being the one whom the Word was **with**. The Word then cannot also **be** god in the literal sense of the term, for God can only be one. 

_**Aid to Biblical Understanding,**_ p. 919 & 1669: "Other translators, also recognizing that the Greek term is used as an adjective to describe the nature of the Word, therefore render the phrase: 'the Word was divine' [...] All these rendering highlights the quality of the word, not his identity with his father, the Almighty God".

Comment: (3) _**Idiom-Book of New Testament Greek,**_ p. 116: "It is necessarily without the article (Θεὸς not ὁ Θεὸς) inasmuch as it describes the nature of the Word and does not identify His Person."

Comment: (4) _**The New Bible Dictionary**_ The Inter-Varsity Fellowship, 1962, p. 744: "The Word possesses a like power to the God who speaks it."

Comment: (5) _**The Fourth Gospel: Its Significance and Environment,**_ p. 99: "The closing words of v. I should be translated, 'the Logos was divine'. Here the word theos has no article, thus giving it the significance of an adjective."

Comment: (6) _**The Gospel of John,**_ by William Barclay, p. 39(a): "Finally John says that the word was God. This is a difficult saying for us to understand, and it is difficult because Greek, in which John wrote, had a different way of saying things from the way in which English speaks. When Greek uses a noun it almost always uses the definite article with it. The Greek for God is theos and the definite article is ho. When Greek speaks about God it does not simply say theos; it says ho theos. Now when Greek does not use the definite article with a noun that noun becomes much more like an adjective."

Comment: (7) _**The Gospel of John,**_ by William Barclay, p. 39(b): "John did not say that the word was ho theos; that would have been to say that the word was identical with God. He said that the word was theos – without the definite article – which means that the word was, we might say, of the very same character and quality and essence and being as God."

Comment: The original greek word order is "God was the word.".  Shouldn't that be maintained?

Comment: Greek sentence-structure and English sentence-structure are different. In Greek, the word-order isn't so much important as the suffixes and articles may be. For example: (1) "ὁ κύριος βλέπει **τον υἱὸν**" and (2) "**τον υἱὸν** βλέπει ὁ κύριος" both mean the same thing: The lord sees **the son**. On the other hand: (1) "**τον κύριον** βλέπει ὁ υἱὸς" and (2) "ὁ υἱὸς βλέπει **τον κύριον**" By switching the articles and suffixes, both phrases (although in different orders) now both say: The son sees **the lord**.

Comment: This might help you: http://www.ibiblio.org/koine/greek/lessons/noun2dcl.html

Comment: It did help, thanks.  At the tail end of John 1:1 both God (θεος) and Word (λογος) are nominative, singular masculine which usually indicates subject.  There is no direct object in the phrase just two subject nouns equated by the third person singular verb.  The verb is imperfect (action in past time), active (subject(s) perform the action), and indicative (represents what actually is).  Because God and Word here are both subjects they can be flipped around in the sentence without changing the meaning.

Comment: That's fine if you ignore all of the other facts, and you clearly know more than all of the scholarly sources I cited, more than experts in the field of Greek linguistics. "The time is coming when people won’t listen to good teaching. Instead, they will look for teachers who will please them by telling them **only what they are itching to hear**." (II Tim. 4:3 CEV) "Don't let anyone forget these things. And with God as your witness, you must warn them **not to argue about words**. These arguments don't help anyone. In fact, they ruin everyone who listens to them." (II Tim. 2:14 CEV)

Comment: Ouch.  Since even the finest scholars bifurcate over this issue I will put my trust in the Son of the living God, who has saved me, and follow His Spirit. 1 Corinthians 2:6-16

Comment: @carsonfel: You're absolutely on the mark with your last comment. It's amazing how many people just want to prove their theology correct even if they are not even able to read basic Koine Greek. By the way, you might be interested in [the ancient Coptic translation of John 1:1](http://inthenameofwhowhat.blogspot.com/2008/05/early-coptic-translation-and-john-11c.html).

Answer (score 2):

The word in question here is the Greek word θεός (Theos), which is a noun.  If "divine" is being used as a noun that is synonymous with "God", I don't see any issue here.  On the other hand, if "divine" is being used as an adjective, that would be an incorrect rendering of the Greek. Theos is not an adjective describing god-like qualities, but a noun referring to God.

Theos is a very standard term for referring to God.  Theos occurs 311 times in the New Testament and always refers to God or false gods. (see [here](https://biblehub.com/greek/theos_2316.htm)). It also occurs more than 1,000 times in various forms.

If Theos doesn't mean God there are an awful lot of passages we would need to re-translate, including significant statements like:

> I am the God of Abraham (Matthew 22:32)

> Who can forgive sins but God alone? (Luke 5:21)

Should Theos be translated as "divine" in those passages? My two cents are that the translation "divine" artificially complicates the passage by hinting at an adjectival meaning not found in the Greek.

Comment: That is all very well but the matter at hand here is Logos is articular and theos is not - hence the qualitative rendering of Maffatt.  Note the Greek construction - καὶ Θεὸς ἦν ὁ Λόγος.

Comment: Oh, I don't necessarily disagree with a qualitative interpretation. I thought "my car is a Ford" or "this animal is a monkey" were good illustrations. I just think in English the use of "divine" can lend itself to misunderstanding because divine is both a noun and an adjective.

Comment: if you feel any more comfortable, then "The Word was Divinity" might help.  I will update my answer to add more information.

Comment: Good clarification; I agree "Divinity" is awkward.  Ah, the joys of translation!

Answer (score 1):

Translations have to pay attention to grammar, but they also have to pay attention to basic logic and cultural cues. Saying "the Logos was with God, and the Logos was God" makes no sense. It fails a basic logic test - something cannot be *with* something and also *be* that something on a normal understanding of these sorts of words. So something's gotta give. The question is what.

Moffatt's translation has the advantage of *making sense*. Something can be both with God and divine. The question "is it representative of the original" is vague. The question I have is, what was the intent with the original sentence? What was John trying to say? How would it typically be received? Was he trying to make a logically (seemingly) paradoxical sentence? Some trinitarians would say he was! Or was he trying to express something else?

Related to this are background beliefs about John's conception of the logos, John's conception of God, and John's conception of Jesus. It is basically impossible to translate this sentence without working beliefs about those respective concepts re John, IMHO.

If you think that logos here = Jesus = person of trinity, you might not have a problem with the typical translation, because 'God' is basically a category containing 3 persons - so the sentence makes sense (in a mysterian kind of way). It could be paraphrased as "God the Son was with God the Father, and God the Son was of the category 'God'".

Yet, is this how ancient Greek culture would have understood the term 'logos'? No. It was, indeed, something related to words - discourse, reason, God's unfolding principle - things like that. If that's your view, how do you translate the last part of John 1:1?

Consider REV [commentary on John 1:1](https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/John/chapter1/1)

> "“the word.” “Word” is translated from the Greek word logos (#3056
> λόγος ). **It refers to God’s reason as played out in His plan and
> purpose.** It is important that Christians have a basic understanding of
> logos, which is translated as “Word” in most versions of John 1:1.
> **Most Trinitarians believe that logos refers directly to Jesus Christ**,
> so in most Bibles logos is capitalized as “Word” (some versions even
> put “Jesus Christ” instead of “Word” in John 1:1). However, a study of
> **the Greek word logos shows that it occurs more than 300 times in the
> New Testament, and in both the NIV and the KJV it is capitalized only
> 7 times** (and even those versions disagree on exactly when to
> capitalize it). When a word that occurs more than 300 times is
> capitalized fewer than 10 times, **it is obvious that when to capitalize
> and when not to capitalize is a translators’ decision based on their
> particular understanding of Scripture**. Below are five points to
> consider. [...]"

I recommend the rest of the commentary at the link above.

As with many things in scripture, where you stand on a 'representative' translation of this line is going to depend on where you sit in terms of background beliefs about the word 'logos', the writer John's beliefs about that word, and so on. Because the REV translators understand 'logos' here as meaning roughly 'plan', they translate John 1:1 as

> In the beginning was the word, and the word was with God, and what God
> was the word was. (ibid.)

And what if we paraphrased it to more accurately convey the intended meaning?

> Once we understand the logos in John 1:1 to be God’s purpose and plan,
> we can see that if John 1:1 was written in today’s English, we would
> likely say something like, **“In the beginning was the plan, and God had
> that plan, and what God was the plan was.”**

Comment: I think it attempts to get across that there is no ontological difference between what God plans/thinks and who God is (as in, He is as good as His word).  He is Spirit of infinite integrity and what He thinks IS God so when His thoughts are made flesh then so is He.  The thinker and the thought are separate and yet identical.

Comment: ὁ λόγος ἦν **πρὸς** τὸν θεόν literally the the Word was **turned** toward God. The idea that the Word was with God as you interpret would be expressed differently, For example ἡνίκα ἡτοίμαζεν τὸν οὐρανόν **συμπαρήμην** αὐτῷ. It is συμπάρειμι which conveys the type of "with" you interpret. In addition, there are several other words to say "with" which would have conveyed "with" closer to the way you interpret. The fact the writer used πρὸς contradicts your assertion that it makes no sense. Just the opposite. it is the second part καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος which establishes unity.

Comment: @RevelationLad I'm just going with the standard translation. For yours, similar deal. Something cannot be 'turned toward' something else and *be* that something else. It makes no sense.

Comment: Well, that is what the Greek states, and the Son can be turned toward the Father.

Comment: @RevelationLad Only if you are imposing a trinitarian (or what have you) lens! Which I discuss in the 4th paragraph above. The text does *not* say 'turned towards the Father'. That would of course make it much less problematic and be much more strongly a statement supporting trinitarianism. A trinitarian 'makes sense' of the typical sort of translation by implicitly paraphrasing the sentence.

Comment: The "Father" is not found in John1:1. The fact you must insert what the writer clearly left out to make your point should alert you to mistake in your assumption. In fact, had the writer simply used "Father" in place of "God" in John 1:1. There would be little support for the Trinity.

Comment: @RevelationLad Huh?

Comment: In the beginning was the Word [no mention of God or Father] and the Word was with God [not the Father] and the Word was God [not the Father]. You must import God=Father to arrive at "turned to the Father." IOW, you must **interpret** what is written to support your belief and obviously your **interpretation** conflicts with the fact John did not write the Word was πρὸς the Father in John 1:1 as he did in 1 John 2:1.

Comment: "You must import God=Father to arrive at "turned to the Father."" Exactly right. I don't understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

It is not representative of the original:

First, "divine" is an adjective, θεὸς is a noun. If the original writer had intended to make such a statement, they could have used the adjective, [θεῖος](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G2304&t=KJV), which means "divine." For example:

> His **divine** power has granted to us all things that pertain to life and godliness, through the knowledge of him who called us to his own glory and excellence, by which he has granted to us his precious and very great promises, so that through them you may become partakers of the **divine** nature, having escaped from the corruption that is in the world because of sinful desire. (2 Peter 1:3-4 ESV)

Second, if the writer intended to represent the Word as having **only** a divine nature, that was done by the first two statements:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God...

There is no need to "muddy the waters" by adding καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος.